# Prove that f is constant on $K$ that is, if $a \in K$ then $f(x)=f(a) \ \ \forall x\in K$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Suppose that $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ and that $a\in K$, where $K$ is a compact connected subset of $\Bbb R^n$  suppose for each $x\in$ $K$, $\exists$ $\delta_x >0$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ $\forall$ $y\in$ $B_{\delta_x}(x)$

Prove that f is constant on $K$ that is, if $a \in K$ then $f(x)=f(a) \ \ \forall x\in K$

Comment: Sorry, I dont have any idea to Try to solve this. Thus, I could not write any comment:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the smarter thing to do here is begin a little bit with with tomasz's approach, which seems to be a bit more elegant in this case.

To show that the desired set is open:

We also notice that for any $x\in f^{-1}(f(a))$, $B_{\delta_x}(x)\subset f^{-1}(f(a))$.  Thus, $f^{-1}(f(a))$ is the union of open sets, and is therefore open.

[then show that the same set is closed, or that its complement is also open]

Thus, we have shown that $f^{-1}(f(a))$ is both closed and open in $K$. Because (why?), it must be that $f^{-1}(f(a))$ is either the empty set or all of $K$.  Since $f^{-1}(f(a))$ is not the empty set, it must be that $f^{-1}(f(a))=K$.  Thus, $f$ must be constant on $K$.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I think similar things. I Try to show the proof by using the hint on that comment. Please can you check this? I just have been starting to learn this topic by myself. So I am not good at solving the question. Also I dont want to learn false. Thank you:)

Comment: Hmm, I think @tomasz's approach for this problem might be better actually.

Comment: Then, I dont know how to solve by using tomasz's hint. Can you please show the proof? I dont really honestly have any idea:(

Comment: @Bstr: If you have further questions about my hint, don't hesitate to ask. :)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: $f$ is not assumed to be continuous, so you can't use that.

Comment: @tomasz ah man, not my day today.  I'll let you handle it :/

Comment: Okay I understand good:) thank you thank you:)) @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Sorry for not asking you.  in fact, in first Omnomnmnom said a hint which I though. After then, s/he suggested your hint better. Thus, I asked to further your hint. I forgot ask to you. Sorry:( but I Will post more and more question until august, 1;-) @tomasz by the way, I like your name/nickname. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: notice that for any $y$, the set of points $x\in K$ such that $f(x)=y$ is open (as a subset of $K$). Deduce that it is also closed: its complement is $\bigcup_{y'\neq y} K\cap f^{-1}[\{y'\}]$, a union of open sets. $K$ is connected, so any subset of $K$ which is open and closed is...?